# how can i fix this problem Because the_gorgeous_login depends on sky_engine &gt;=0.0.2 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dependencies

Process failed
Pub get failed
Resolving dependencies in /var/workspace/hot-projects/1212903...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.0.
Because the_gorgeous_login depends on sky_engine >=0.0.2 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.
The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
pub get failed (1; For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety)

I`ve tried to update the sdk but the error is still there